# Loop to filter out lines from apache log files

Tags: linux, bash, loops, grep

I have several apache access files that I would like to clean up a bit before I analyze them. I am trying to use grep in the following way:

```
grep -v term_to_grep apache_access_log
```

I have several terms that I want to grep, so I am piping every grep action as follow:

```
grep -v term_to_grep_1 apache_access_log | grep -v term_to_grep_2 | grep -v term_to_grep_3 | grep -v term_to_grep_n > apache_access_log_cleaned
```

Until here my rudimentary script works as expected! But I have many apache access logs, and I don't want to do that for every file. I have started to write a bash script but so far I couldn't make it work. This is my try:

```
for logs in ./access_logs/*;
do
    cat $logs | grep -v term_to_grep | grep -v term_to_grep_2 | grep -v term_to_grep_3 | grep -v term_to_grep_n > $logs_clean
done;
```

Could anyone point me out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's the error message? You should quote your `$log` variable. You can use `grep 'foo\|bar'` or `egrep foo|bar` for alternation.

Comment: I quoted '$log' and now I am getting: cat: '$log': No such file or directory. My script is outside of the /access_logs folder

Comment: Well I mean you should actually quote like this: `"$logs"`.

Comment: Wrong quotes! If you want to let Bash expand the variable inside quotes, you need to use double quotes; single quotes inhibit any expansion.

Comment: *What* doesn't work?

Comment: Do you get an "ambiguous redirect" error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a variable and you append `_clean` to its name, that's a *new variable*, and not the value of the old one with `_clean` appended. To fix that, use curly braces:

```
$ var=file.log
$ echo "<$var>"
<file.log>
$ echo "<$var_clean>"
<>
$ echo "<${var}_clean>"
<file.log_clean>
```

Without it, your pipeline tries to redirect to the empty string, which results in an error. Note that `"$file"_clean` would also work.

As for your pipeline, you could combine that into a single grep command:

```sh
grep -Ev 'term_to_grep|term_to_grep_2|term_to_grep_3|term_to_grep_n' "$logs" > "${logs}_clean"
```

No `cat` needed, only a single invocation of grep.

Or you could stick all your terms into a file:

```
$ cat excludes
term_to_grep_1
term_to_grep_2
term_to_grep_3
term_to_grep_n
```

and then use the `-f` option:

```
grep -vf excludes "$logs" > "${logs}_clean"
```

If your terms are strings and not regular expressions, you might be able to speed this up by using `-F` ("fixed strings"):

```
grep -vFf excludes "$logs" > "${logs}_clean"
```

I think GNU grep checks that for you on its own, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That actually solve my problem and make me learn something new! Now I am getting a separate new renamed file for each Apache access file in my folder!

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over several files, but in your loop you constantly overwrite your result file, so it will only contain the last result from the last file.

You don't need a loop, use this instead:

```
egrep -v 'term_to_grep|term_to_grep_2|term_to_grep_3' ./access_logs/* > "$logs_clean"
```

---

Note, it is always helpful to start a Bash script with `set -eEuCo pipefail`. This catches most common errors -- it would have stopped with an error when you tried to clobber the `$logs_clean` file.